# Use android.net.Uri in Java module (within Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, module, uri

I'm developing a Java module which will take care of the communication to an Rest API. For now I'll only use it for an Android application but later I might use it for other environments as well.

The app holds a list of android.net.Uri objects which where received from another app. The android.net.Uri is not a Java class and therefor I cannot use it in the module. I can't get the File path either cause they are protected. 
I could send over a Stream object but than I need to open all streams together cause the logic in the module requires to retrieve all the assets at ones.

Do you have any ideas? Or should I just make an Android module?

Comment: hey, I would like to learn, how you would be making a module for android which can be used somewhere else

Comment: I'm sorry man. I think you should open another question for that.

Comment: @BenGroot I know it's been a long time but I'm in the same situation and curious. Which solution did you go for?